# Keyboard and touchpad not working during 2016 12" MacBook install

Tags: keyboard, touchpad, macbook

I recently got a 2016 12" MacBook and am attempting to install Ubuntu 16.04 on it.

I created a live USB using [Mac Linux USB Loader](https://sevenbits.github.io/Mac-Linux-USB-Loader/) as recommended by UNetbootin's website. With the boot options `noacpi nomodeset` Ubuntu successfully boots into live mode. However, the keyboard and touchpad do not work.

This behavior is apparently also observed by the [Arch folks](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MacBook#April_2016_12.22_-_Version_9.2C1):

```
The keyboard and the touchpad do not work (still looking for a solution).
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

**EDIT: (11-30-2016)**
Someone has written an SPI driver to try to address this problem. You can find it on github [here](https://github.com/cb22/macbook12-spi-driver). I haven't tried it out yet, but if it works any hope this will make it into the kernel?

Answer (score 0):

Yes!

There is definitely hope. There has been a a [patch submitted to the Linux Kernel Mailing list](https://lkml.org/lkml/2019/2/4/69)

it's unclear if it will make it into the 5.1 Kernel cycle of if we have to wait longer.

Until then use can install using an external USB keyboard and then follow the instructions on the github repo you linked to get the keyboard working