# install ubuntu on macbook 9,1 (released 2016)

Tags: macbook

I just got a new Macbook 9,1 (released in 2016, and not Macbook Pro 9,1!!) and am new to Ubuntu. Does Macbook 9,1 support the latest verison of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3):

You can always try the Live CD. If it boots up and runs properly, all your hardware is supported. If your Macbook doesn't have a CD drive, make a bootable USB stick. Be forewarned, the LiveCD is slower that the real thing.

Comment: So is the hardware of the latest Macbook supported by the latest Ubuntu? For instance, I searched [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/794941/keyboard-and-touchpad-not-working-during-2016-12-macbook-install), which has a [negative answer](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MacBook#April_2016_12.22_-_Version_9.2C1).

Answer (score 1):

You will have quite a few driver problems. If you are capable of dealing with that and a boot manager like rEFInd, then it's pretty simple if you have a USB-c to USB-a dongle with 2 USB-a ports or a USB-a hub with your USB-c to USB-a dongle.

You will also need to install gdisk (gpt fdisk for Mac). The commands for it and a more detailed installation for Macs in general can be found [here](http://www.rodsbooks.com/ubuntu-efi/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to fix touchpad and keyboard on macbook9.1, read the few last posts at
https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=99891
Though now I can't boot livecd on macbook9.1 2016 without passing acpi=off
but that seems to make ssd undetectable :(
I've tested ubuntu 16.04.1 a month ago on macbook9.1 2015 and livecd boots ok without that option and ssd was right there.
I've tried to make a topic on this but it was closed as "duplicate"